# How to pick an option automatically in dialog boxes when updating ssh with apt?

Tags: linux, ssh, apt, raspbian

Just installed raspbian lite buster for my headless raspberry pi, and set up weekly updates with cron. However, I noticed a small problem when I ran a manual upgrade first. SSH had a new version available, and opened a full-screen popup to ask if I wanted to use their config file or keep my own. Because of some settings I changed including not using port 22, it was important that my config file stays. However, if I am not around to select that option, then the system will theoretically stay at that point forever. I can't set it up to just pick the first option either, because that would overwrite my config file and leave me unable to log in with ssh. How do I make it so if this appears again, the *second* option gets selected automatically?